# Testing a Kotest test

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotest

I am not sure if this is possible or if there's a better architecture for this. I wrote a function that does some tests:

```
fun validate(a: Any?, b: Any?){
   a shouldBe b
}
```

My function is obviously more complex than that, but now I would like to test the test itself. For example, I want to pass `a=1` and `b=null` and make sure it fails.  Is there a way to test for it to fail or succeed using `Kotest`?

If not, what is a proper way to architect this?

I am trying to rely on this test often and in many places of my service, so I would like it to be as reliable as possible.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about why you need to test a test. What's next, testing the test of the test? Why do you need to test a test?

Comment: It's just a generic testing function that does a common set of validations we do in this project. It would save us many lines of code and some errors every time we're writing new specs. I want to make sure those validations are properly done before using it all over

Comment: If you use the TDD approach, you will first write a failing test. If the test doesn't fail at the start, there's something wrong with the test. Fix the test so that it fails. Then fix the production code so that it passes the test. This way, you've tested both the test and the production code. However, if you're righting a test for existing code which has so far not been tested, you can't use this technique. Instead, just write the test, put a temporary bug in your production code, see the test fail as expected, then remove the temporary bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: use `shouldFail { ... }`.

This is possible because failing tests in Kotest (and many other frameworks) will throw an `AssertionError`. You can check for that exception to see whether the test failed. So to check for a failed assertion, you can write:

```kotlin
shouldThrow<AssertionError> { /* your failing test here */ }
```

As you'd probably expect, `shouldThrow` will catch the exception so that it doesn't propagate. So in effect it will turn a failing test into a passing test, and vice versa.

To make it a bit more convenient and readable, you could write a couple of extension functions, like this:

```kotlin
fun shouldFail(block: () -> Unit) = shouldThrow<AssertionError>(block)
fun shouldNotFail(block: () -> Unit) = shouldNotThrow<AssertionError>(block)
```

In fact Kotest includes the `shouldFail` function in the standard assertions, so you don't even need to define it yourself. Their implementation is the same as what I have suggested here. They don't include a `shouldNotFail`, though, presumably because the usefulness is a bit questionable. Wrapping a test in "shouldNotFail" makes it fail if the assertion fails and pass if the assertion passes, which is... exactly what it would have done if you didn't wrap it in anything at all.

To test your own assertion functions, you can use it like this:

```kotlin
shouldFail { 1 shouldBe 2 }
```

If you look at the [source code for Kotest](https://github.com/kotest/kotest) itself, you'll find many unit tests for the built-in assertion functions using exactly this approach.